# Laravel Authentication "Remember Me" token

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, remember-me

I'm working on one project, where I have to make "Remember Me" on authentication, but I have one problem. The company uses "users" table for users, and "login" table for remember token, IP address and login date.

I have found that if I want to have "Remember Me" on authentication, I have "remember_token" in my "users" table. But can I have the "remember_token" in another table and connect it by some relations?

Comment: Yes, you can have the "remember_token" in another table and connect it by some relations

Comment: and how to make this?

Comment: How does your  login table look like? it should have a user_id field, has it? If so, you have a One-To-Many relationship.

Comment: I have "users" table with `nickname`, and "login" table with `userid` (where is stored users->nickname).
and I have `usertoken` in "login" table.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to put remember me (cookie) in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27499512/how-to-put-remember-me-cookie-in-php)

Comment: Try to add a data model diagram of the tables, so that it is easier to visualise. This will enable users to help you in a much better way. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new migration that can add a new field to users table:
`php artisan make:migration add_remember_token_field_to_users_table`
This will create a migration for table users, then add this code:

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->rememberToken();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('remember_token');
        });
    }
```